# Classes in lisp

Tags: c++, common-lisp

I wanted to define a class in lisp its very simple in the c++ the code would be something like this

```
    class intersection{
    int distance;
    int fuel;
    char node1;
    char node2;
};
```

how can i write this in lisp and define objects from it
Thank you

Comment: Have you read anything about Lisp at all? Have you done any fundamental coding with Lisp?

Comment: This is a matter for a [book on CLOS](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html), not an SO question.

Comment: @outis: How is a Lisp (or CLOS) question *not* about programming?

Comment: @Marcelo: It's not that it's not about programming, it's that the question is far too broad in scope. Hence, not a good fit for SO, as described in the FAQ.

Comment: @outis: Nonsense. The OP wants to define a class in Lisp and doesn't know how to do it. It is a very clear, unambiguous question with several good and very specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Common Lisp Object System, a part of ANSI Common Lisp.

```
(defclass intersection-class ()
  ((distance :type integer)
   (fuel     :type integer)
   (node1    :type character)
   (node2    :type character)))

CL-USER 69 > (make-instance 'intersection-class)
#<INTERSECTION-CLASS 4020002C2B>
```

Answer (score 1):

In [CLOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System), in its simplest form, you'd use `defclass`:

```
(defclass intersection ()
  (distance
   fuel
   node1
   node2))
```

Answer (score -1):

That isn't a class; it's just a data structure (and not a very useful one until you add `public:` at the top or replace `class` with `struct`). You could use an [a-list](http://www.ida.liu.se/imported/cltl/clm/node153.html) for this purpose.

I don't know what you mean by "define objects from it". If you mean "instantiate it", creating an a-list is fairly trivial: `'((distance . 10) (fuel . 85) (node1 . #\a) (node2 . #\z))`.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way of handling abstraction is to create a list with the type in the first element and the data in the rest, I would use something along these lines to create an object:

```
(list 'intersection distance fuel node1 node2)
```

And something like this if you want a "constructor"

```
(defun createIntersection (d f n1 n2)
    (list 'intersection, d f n1 n2))
```

Comment: oh, sorry. Haven't actually coded lisp for 6 years. Fixing...